# Printing json object value in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, rest

Here in my code my submitting username and password in json format to restful service get method. In return, this method returns json object which i am unable to show on my two text box in jquery.

Here is my jsp page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var uname = $("#uname").val();
        var pwd = $("#pwd").val();
        authenticate(uname, pwd);
    });
});

//authenticate function to make ajax call
function authenticate(uname, pwd) {

    $.ajax
    ({
      type: 'GET',
        //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
        url: 'REST/WebService/GetLogin',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        //json object to sent to the authentication url
        data:{'uname': uname, 'pwd': pwd },

        error:function()
        {
            alert("unsuccessfull");
        },
        success:function(server_response)
        {   
            $( '#message' ).text( server_response.message);
            $( '#lastname' ).text( server_response.lastname);
            alert("successfull");
        }

     });
}
</script>
```

```
<input type="text" id="message"></input><br/>
<input type="text" id="lastname"></input><br/>

UserName:<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"/><br/>
Password:<input type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="LogIn"/>
```

My restful get method:

```
   @Path("/WebService")
   public class LoginService{
@GET
@Path("/GetLogin")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")


public String loginFeed(@QueryParam("uname") String uname,@QueryParam("pwd") String pwd )
{
    String feeds  = null;

    try 
    {
        ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedData = null;
        ProjectManager projectManager= new ProjectManager();
        feedData=projectManager.GetLogin(uname, pwd);

        feeds=FeedTransformer.UserFeed(feedData);
        System.out.println("inside");

     } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    return feeds;

}
```

This feeds is in the form of json object.

Comment: What do you get instead of the excepted result? Any errors? I'd suggest to use the Firefox plugin "Firebug" which allows you to analyze the network communication. This way you would just see your JSON result in Firebug. What headers does your server-part use? If it is not JSON, you may either want to tell jQuery that the result will be in JSON or you may want to make use of `var server_message_json = $.parseJSON(server_message);` **Edit:** just noted you actually **did** submit the dataType. Anyway, Firebug may save you from many sleepness nights full of headache, there.

Comment: My response is in json from restful service implementation ie @Produces("application/json")

Answer (score 0):

In the success: option you should use the build-in CONSOLE in your browser and add the following:

```
console.log(server_response); //this bad boy will tell you whats up
```

If this doesn't get you anywhere then also check the NETWORK tab in your console window to see whether or not the script is failing.

Also, i don't quite know if it matters but I always start with a slash in the URL just to be safe:

```
url: '/REST/WebService/GetLogin',
```

Try serializing the data rather than manually creating the string maybe:

```
data: $('TARGET_YOUR_FORM').serialize()
```

Comment: Also on doing console.log my json format is correctly showing as [{"message":"wow","lastname":"ri"}], now i don't how can i parsed it on client side

Comment: That it very strange. Can you try printing the response without explicitly setting a header? I use PHP and if I do not set the header information then it provides text/html to the browser but my AJAX call still parses it as a json string because of the dataType which you also have set to json. Another thought is that maybe there is a bug in your jQuery version or even your browser? I am using jQuery 1.10.2.

Comment: i have specified javascript source as http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Did you have any luck using Chris S.'s suggestion to do $.parseJSON(server_message); ? This might fix the issue but it is only a band-aid solution. There must be some root cause of jQuery not being able to handle that string as JSON.

Comment: Also firefox debugger also showing Object { message="wow", lastname="tiwari"}

Comment: What if you tried to send @Produces("text/json") instead of @Produces("application/json")?

Comment: Values are printed with $.each(feeds, function (index, value) {
        alert(value.message);
    }); ----thanks to firebug great help

Comment: Hey, not sure if you've worked through this issue or not by now but my json looks a touch different than yours. Mine outputs  {"message":"wow","lastname":"ri"} with no square braces on the outside. I know they both validate through JSONlint.com but just thought I would let you know.